# How do I stop an anchor tag from scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, scroll, anchor

I am trying to stop an anchor tag from scrolling after it is clicked, it is not posting back but scrolling to the location:

```
$('.moo').click(function (evt) {
        // stops from submitting the form   

        return false;
    });


<a href="#tabs-1" class="moo" >Nunc tincidunt</a>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So do you mean that the #tabs-1 appears in your address bar and the content is scrolled down to #tabs-1?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `javascript:void(0)` as the `href`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="moo" >Nunc tincidunt</a>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wR6B/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the function `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$('.moo').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But as far as I can see there is nothing wrong, I created a JsFiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/egQms/

Comment: I added a JsFiddle example, as far a I can see there is nothing wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `evt.preventDefault()`. This will stop the browser from performing the default action for the event.